# How to enable the Customer Information Manager (CIM) in Authorize.net?

Tags: e-commerce, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

When i am storing the credit card information in customer information manager its showing "E00044Customer Information Manager is not enabled" error. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

That would indicate that CIM has not been activated for that account. If this is a live account you'll need to sign up for CIM. If this is a dev account you'll need to activate it in your control panel.

Comment: How do you activate it ? i can't seem to find it

Comment: My problem turned out to be that I was using `accept.authorize.net` instead of `test.authorize.net` for my API calls.

Answer (score 5):

CIM costs $20/month for a live account. You can easily enable it from the left menu on your dashboard.

If you would like to have CIM enabled in your test account, make sure you sign up for a "Card Not Present" type from [here](https://developer.authorize.net/testaccount/).

Helpful link for developer. Click [here](https://developer.authorize.net/api/cim/).

Answer (score 2):

It's under Account -> Merchant Profile -> Additional Services

Answer (score 1):

Log in to authorize.net, on the left looks for "Customer Information Management", click that, read the page and click to add the $20/month charge to your account.